# How to use to use 2 TfidfVectorizer in same classification task using FeatureUnion

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification

**Is this possible / advisable theoretically to use more than one `TfidfVectorizer` in same task**?

So I have this pipeline where I use the metadata for a classification task like length of text, no of tokens etc.

```
def get_numeric_data(df):
    return [record[:-2].astype(float) for record in df]

def get_text_data(df):
    return [record[-1] for record in df]

transfomer_numeric = FunctionTransformer(get_numeric_data)
transformer_text = FunctionTransformer(get_text_data)

# Create a pipeline to concatenate Tfidf Vector and Numeric data
# Use RandomForestClassifier as an example
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
            ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', transfomer_numeric)
            ])),
             ('text_features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', transformer_text),
                ('vec', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word'))
            ]))
         ])),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
])
```

I have a unique problem where in one pipeline I have text only and in other one, I have the latex where I use special charas and special symbols.

**I want to know can I use 2 different `TfidfVectorizer` in this task? And if yes, how can I?**

Comment: To answer this reliably, we might need more information on the application/dataset that you're using the tokenizer for. Are you intending to parse documents with mixed-LaTex and unicode content? Or are you intending to parse documents into their unicode and LaTeX contents separately and analyze them independently? What's the end-goal?

Comment: I am testing the possibility of passing text and latex separately. I have tried together but the tokenizer has to be different for text and latex.